# How to access Spring context in jUnit tests annotated with @RunWith and @ContextConfiguration?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test, applicationcontext

I have following test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/services-test-config.xml"})
public class MySericeTest {

  @Autowired
  MyService service;
...

}
```

Is it possible to access `services-test-config.xml` programmatically in one of such methods? Like:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = somehowGetContext();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible even with the vanilla runner `JUnit4.class`, which the answers are ignoring. I need to Google around a bit more.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Since the tests will be instantiated like a Spring bean too, you just need to implement the ApplicationContextAware interface:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/services-test-config.xml"})
public class MySericeTest implements ApplicationContextAware
{

  @Autowired
  MyService service;
...
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException
    {
        // Do something with the context here
    }
}
```

For non xml needs, you can also do this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
/* must provide some "root" for the app-context, use unit-test file name to the context is empty */
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyUnitTestClass.class)
public class MyUnitTestClass implements ApplicationContextAware {
```

Comment: Not possible in Spring 3.0 and up, up to this date.

Answer (score 95):

This works fine too:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;
```

Comment: Confirmed, in Spring Integration 3.0.2. Neatest solution.

Comment: However this solution is viable only if you are using it into a managed bean.  By implementing ApplicationContextAware is working well even in a POJO

Comment: Works fine on spring 4.2

Answer (score 9):

If your test class extends the Spring JUnit classes
(e.g., `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` or any other class that extends `AbstractSpringContextTests`), you can access the app context by calling the `getContext()` method.
Check out the [javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/index.html) for the package org.springframework.test.

Comment: Is there any difference when using the AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests, or AbstractSpringContextTests vs simply extending ApplicationContextAware in my junit test? What benefits are provided by the 2 abstract test classes suggested in this answer?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to inject instance of `ApplicationContext` class by using `SpringClassRule`
and `SpringMethodRule` rules. It might be very handy if you would like to use
another non-Spring runners. Here's an example:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BeanConfiguration.class)
public static class SpringRuleUsage {

    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule springClassRule = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void shouldInjectContext() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created one post related to this issue, this really helpful to gain confidence

[Try this link for more details](https://sudeep.mytechexp.com/2023/07/how-to-test-application-context-in.html)

```
@Test
void TestBeanLaunch()
{
    context.run(it -> {
        /*
         * I can use assertThat to assert on the context
         * and check if the @Bean configured is present
         * (and unique)
         */
        assertThat(it).hasSingleBean(PracticeApplication.class);
        assertThat(it).hasSingleBean(PracticeApplication.TestBean.class);
        assertThat(it.getBean("BeanTest")).isInstanceOf(PracticeApplication.TestBean.class);
    });
}
```