# how are annoted beans available in junit?

Tags: spring, junit, applicationcontext

An existing project that I work on, has a Spring bean that's created with Java:

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfiguration
{
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @Bean(name = "edielbean")
  public EdielBean edielBean()
  {
    return new EdielBean();
  }
}
```

Now I want to access that bean from my unit test. My question is similar to [How to access Spring context in jUnit tests annotated with @RunWith and @ContextConfiguration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425015/how-to-access-spring-context-in-junit-tests-annotated-with-runwith-and-context) except that my bean is not in XML but in Java.

I tried by adding this unit test (the camel parts can be ignored):

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class EdielBeanTest extends CamelTestSupport implements ApplicationContextAware {

private ApplicationContext context;

@Override
public String isMockEndpoints() {
  // camel
  return "*";
}

@Test
public void testSupplierSwitch() throws Exception
{
  getMockEndpoint("mock:market-out").expectedMessageCount(1); // camel
  System.out.println("beans: "+context.getBeanDefinitionCount());
  for (String name: context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
    System.out.println(name);
  }
  EdielBean edielBean = (EdielBean)context.getBean("edielbean");
  edielBean.startSupplierSwitch(createCustomer(), createOrder(), "54", "43");

  assertMockEndpointsSatisfied(); // camel
}

private Customer createCustomer()
{
  Customer customer = new Customer();
  // .... part omitted    
  return customer;
}

private Order createOrder() {
  Order order = new Order();
  // .... part omitted
  return order;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
    throws BeansException {
  this.context = context;
}

}
```

The console output shows there are only trivial beans:

```
...
beans: 6
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessorSep 
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor
...
```

test output:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'edielbean' is defined
    at
    ....
    at com.essent.belgium.ediel.services.EdielBeanTest.testSupplierSwitch(EdielBeanTest.java:42)
    at 
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never worked with Camel, so I'm not sure if this will work in your case, but this is how I would change your unit tests to work:

**BeansConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name = "edielbean")
    public EdielBean edielBean()
    {
        return new EdielBean();
    }
}
```

**EdielBeanTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BeansConfiguration.class)
public class EdielBeanTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public String isMockEndpoints() {
        // camel
        return "*";
    }

    @Test
    public void testSupplierSwitch() throws Exception
    {
        getMockEndpoint("mock:market-out").expectedMessageCount(1); // camel
        System.out.println("beans: " + context.getBeanDefinitionCount());
        for (String name : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        EdielBean edielBean = (EdielBean) context.getBean("edielbean");
        edielBean.startSupplierSwitch(createCustomer(), createOrder(), "54", "43");

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied(); // camel
    }

    private Customer createCustomer()
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        // .... part omitted
        return customer;
    }

    private Order createOrder() {
        Order order = new Order();
        // .... part omitted
        return order;
    }
}
```

I removed the implementation of `ApplicationContextAware`, Autowired the ApplicationContext, and changed `@ContextConfiguration` to point to your `BeansConfiguration` class. The last one may not be correct if the BeansConfiguration class is loaded by another JavaConfig class. In that case, you should point ContextConfiguration to the parent configuration.